# Converting and deleting audio files in multiple directories using batch for loop

Tags: cmd, batch-processing

I want to process multiple audio files. What I want to do is take `.m4a` files in directory and for each of one do this:

- `faad` (it converts the .m4p file to a `.wave` file but keeps the .m4p file)
- `oddenc` on the new .wave file, this creates an .ogg file
- `del` the `.m4a` file and the `.wave`file.
- Move to the next `.m4a` in the directory

Also I need it to do it to multiple folders (recursively).

What i have works, but it's messy. If first goes through the folders and creates `.wave` and `.ogg` files everywhere.
This means I suddenly have all the `.m4p`s `.wave`s and `.ogg`s in the same folders, before they get deleted. It uses lots of space and I think there must be a way of converting each file and deleting it as it goes along.

This is what I have so far:

```
>for /r %%i in (*.m4a) do faad "%%i"  
for /r %%i in (*.wav) do oggenc "%%i"  
for /r %%i in (*.m4a) do del "%%i"  
for /r %%i in (*.wav) do del "%%i"
```

But I want something like:

```
>for /r %%i in (*.mpa) do faad "%%i" (*wav) do oggenc "%%i" (*m4a) do del "%%i" (*wav) do del "%%i"
```

Is there a way I could achieve that this works? Because the above code doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting braces for multiple commands, and %~n to get the filename (without extension) from the parameter:

```
::: Please define folder to search in (recursively)
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^:::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF

for /f %%i in ('dir %1\*.mp4 /b/s') do (
  faad "%%i"
  oggenc "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni.wav"
  del "%%~ni.m4a"
  del "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni.wav"
)
```

This relies on faad turning `filename.mp4` -> `filename.wav`

Update: You need to supply 1 command line argument - the folder to recursively search, that is, all subfolders will be checkd for mp4 files and processed.

Comment: I should note that im using Windows7

Comment: Try prefixing line 2+3 with echo (`echo faad "%%i"`) and commenting out line 4+5 (the deletes) and see what is printed on screen.  Without `faad` and `oggenc` I can't test what is isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Rudi. I did as suggested, but when i run the script it just exits. even if put a pause at the end of the script it ignores the pause and exits. It`s got me perplexed

Comment: for /r %%i in (*.m4a) do faad "%%i"
for /r %%i in (*.wav) do oggenc "%%i" works but as i said it`s a resource hog

Comment: @Kam - Opps!  I updated the code, I was missing the %% marks for lines 3,4,5. (Which was the error message I was getting)  The resource-hoggy nature of this process isn't likely to be reduced that much by this arrangement over multiple for loops.

Comment: Okay im starting to get somewhere, the code wasnt running because i needed to have two %% in the %~ni so it would be like %%~ni. Well it gets past the first bit and creates the Wave,but then "error".The next line Oggenc "%%~ni.wav" seems to work but it spits out an error Cannot open input file"Sound_005.wav" No such file or directory.And That is weird because when i check the folder it`s there.I added the pause`s just to check what was happening. Any idea`s Rudi :)
for /r %%i in (*.mp4) do (
 faad "%%i" 
pause
 oggenc "%%~ni.wav"
pause )
(
pause

Comment: Are you certain "Sound_005.wav" exists with exactly that name?  Is it in the same folder or some subfolder? Does oggenc deal with long filenames? (your example filename is >8.3)  If your filenames are also without spaces/special characters you can drop the quotes around `%%~ni.wav` (oggenc maynot be properly dealing with these).

Comment: okay i can get it to work, but only if the .mp4 files are in the same dir as the batch script  this is what i have so far                    for /r %%i in (*.mp4) do (
 faad "%%i" 
pause
oggenc %%~ni.wav
pause )
but in sub folers it only converts the .mp4 to .wav,it displays in the CMD window that its also creating .ogg`s but it doesn`t.Just the Main diectory works.Ill try the /s command instead of /r   maybe that will help lol 6.40am been working on this since 10pm yesterday

Comment: actually it doesnt say its working in sub folders. I have a folder named FEET and in that folder there is 20 more folders with names such as BANK_001 and so on. in each of those folders will be manny .mp4 files with different names but repeating in the other folders eg Sound_005.mp4 may be the name of a file in all 20 folders, though the sound itself is different.Dont understand why oggenc will only work in the root dir while faad works in all subs

Comment: {Updated (above)} Say you want to process `c:\FEET` and the batch file is called `looper.bat` call: `looper c:\FEET` (to process all mp4 files in and subfolders).

Comment: When you said to define the folders to search, do you mean   put  dir F:\AudioCompressing\CONVERTING\FEET                at the start of the code where Feet is the starting dir. this didnt work instant exit. also tried CD path of folder to convert, same deal exit. I should addmitt though that im just a Hack when it comes to codding.

Comment: Well this is a strange one. The Code seems to work but gets stuck in an infinite loop. could be because i echoed the del functions though so ill check that out. Its weird that i have to call the script from another script for it to work, but hey if its not broken...  I put F:\AudioCompressing\CONVERTING\FEET at the start of the Mp42Ogg.bat script  then called the script  in a CallMp42Ogg.bat script. When i execute the CallMp42Ogg.bat it does execute the script and it seems to work. but it goes on a loop that never stops..?

Comment: echo ::: Please define folder to search in (recursively)
F:\AudioCompressing\CONVERTING\GENRL

if "%~1"=="" findstr "^:::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF

for /f %%i in ('dir %1\*.mp4 /b/s') do (
  faad "%%i"

  oggenc "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni.wav"
 del "%%~ni.mp4"
 del "%%~di%%~pi%%~ni.wav"
)

Comment: Doesnt delete the .mp4 or .wave and seems to loop recursively. It will go into the first folder Convert .mp4 to .wav to .ogg then not delete the .wav .mp4 then it goes to the next folder and does the same, it then goes back to the first folder and repeats itself and then the second folder.  It then moves to the third folder and does the same going back to the first ect The pattern is there but i have no idea why its doing it. Could it be the script that calls the Mp42Ogg.bat       Because all that has in it is Call Mp42Ogg.bat    Your help has been greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using [dir2ogg](http://jak-linux.org/projects/dir2ogg/) to simplify the process if you have Python installed.  It might be a bit of a challenge to get the binaries it's dependent on installed in Windows, though.

Comment: Looked into it but the script has to be run on Computers that might not have python

Comment: I should note that im using Windows7